# How to run java program only for 1 second?

Tags: java, performance, compiler-construction

I need to calibrate the machines, so my goal is to run a java program approximately for 1 second. So I could use the same program on other machine to measure their run time and calibrate it to 1 second.

I know 1 second run time is too small, it depends on various factors. But I was wondering if you guys could have any ideas that you would like to share about the calibration.

I want to run a java program for approximately one second. I want compiler to perform certain standard operations on an array. I have tried using for an array to find even and odd numbers.

The program output is not that important. The run time just has to be approximately for 1 second. The problem is that since 1 second is too small number, it gives a fluctuating run time like 1.25 sometimes or 0.678 sometimes.

Is there any way to force compiler only for 1 second without giving a large value of error.

PS: I do not want to use Thread.sleep(1000).

Right now, this is the code I am using. As I said, I am not bothered about the output and the operations as such. I just need a run time as 1 second. Please help me if you have any ideas.

```
long[] array = new long[5000000];
    int repeat = 10;
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int j = 0; j <=repeat; j++)
    {
        int even = 0, odd = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = i;
        }

        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] % 2 == 0)
                even++;
            else
                odd++;
        }
    }
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long t3 = t2 - t1;
    System.out.println(t3*10e-4+ " sec");
```

Comment: You keep referring to the "compiler", when you really mean your compiled application. In any event, I've voted to close this as "too localized" - I can't imagine anyone else needing this solution in the future. Very obscure.

Comment: The compiler doesn't "perform operations" like you imply.  It does perform operations, but those only consist of encoding translation.

Comment: Yeah, right. I just need my program to run for approximately 1 second. the program should perform certain standard oeprations on array.

Comment: Any good reason why `Thread.sleep(1000)` would not do the job!?

Comment: Hit and Trial is the only way. i think add some redundant lines if the code runs for less than 1 sec.
Also you are not calculating the exact time for which this code executes as there are lines before and after t1 and t2.

Comment: Why do you need this, looks like an interview question :-)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do such thing. Running time of such operations depends on too many factors, hardware, JVM so things beyond your control.

Comment: The reason is that, I need to calibrate/standardize platforms. I want a program to run for 1 second on my machine and when I run the same program on a faster machine I want a run time which is <1 and on slower machine > 1 sec. So, I need to calibrate two computing platforms. If i use Thread.sleep() it will run for 1 second on other machine which I do not want. Hence, I am using standard sets of operation on an array

Comment: How about using a `java.util.Timer`?

Comment: Run time of a program will not always be a constant value due to process scheduling done by the CPU.Hence it cannot be used to standardize a platform

Comment: @PankajGadge: You'll only be testing one very specific aspect of performance though. That won't calibrate the "general" performance.

Comment: You should update your question and clarify that your aim is calibration!!!

Comment: create a thread class , after one sec ,destroy the thread , and inside the threads run method , write your prog to be executed for one sec

Answer (score 2):

Hi I would recommend you to do this.

while(!(System.currentTimeMillis() - t1 >= 1000))
{
 ... your program
}
System.exit(0);

Comment: What if execution gets blocked during your program? This would run for longer than 1 second

Answer (score 0):

And for the record with skills in algorythms if you really don't need to remember all these number dont use the array.

you could get the same functionality in this code

for(int j = 0; j <=repeat; j++)

```
{
    int even = 0, odd = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0){
           even++;
        }else{
            odd++;
        }
    }
}
```

you will see it will run faster because you are not doing so many operations ... and you completly cut off the for cycle to 5000000 10 times

I hope this helped you improve the time